# Is there any way to track screens when using react navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, screen

As a developing assistant, I need to to track screens in order to use 'react-native-firebase' package. Firstly, I used `analytics().setCurrentScreen('ViewName')` with using `useEffect` hook. However, I think it is ineffective because there may be a lot of ways to access the screen. Moreover, when I use `goBack` function of react-navigation, `useEffect` hook can't track because the 'formerly opened' screen is not closed.

In order to track screens precisely, I want to find the function to track `screen` variables. Here is a part of the code that my team is developing

```
import {createStackNavigator, createAppContainer, } from 'react-navigation';
...

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Main: {screen: Main,},
...
)};
```

How can I track screens using react-navigation?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be well documented here:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-tracking/